# How to say that someone is the opposite of something

Tags: meaning

If I say

> There are stupid guys, and there's Joe

Does this mean that Joe is stupid or that he is the opposite?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything without further context. All that's provided is a name. Anything you assume is just that. An assumption.

Answer (score 3):

It would normally be understood to mean that Joe takes "stupid" to new levels. He's very, very stupid, unbelievably stupid.

> There's fast, and then there's Usain Bolt.
>
> There are sprinters, and there's Usain Bolt.  [noun phrase instead of adjective]
>
> There are big gold nuggets, and there's Welcome Stranger.
>
> There's fresh, and there's Lysol fresh.
>
> There's clean, and there's {brand-name-soap I can't remember} clean.

Answer (score 1):

I would always use *then* in this kind of phrase:

> There are stupid guys, and **then** there's Joe.

Using *then* allows *Joe* to be considered differently from the "stupid guys".

As written I think it would be understood that Joe is not stupid. Although he could be smart, or really stupid. Just something different.